# getting a string from data attributes of grandchildren

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.b2').on('click', function(){
 //var str = ...
 console.log(str);
});
```

```css
.b2{
background:gold;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='b2'>
  <div class='singleb2'>
  <img class='imgbann' src='00.jpg' data-id=53 alt='img'>
</div>

  <div class='singleb2'>
  <img class='imgbann' src='01.jpg' data-id=66 alt='img'>
</div>
</div>
```

result should be `53-66`

So clicking on `b2` I need a string composed from `data-id` of its grandchildren, joined with `-`.

Any help?

Comment: Are you getting an error of some kind? What have you tried?

Comment: @zfrisch, I tried a double `each` (one for children and one for grandchildren), it works, but I suppose there is a shorter way.

Comment: are the grandchildren all going to have the same class?

Comment: @zfrisch, yes, classes are the same on the same level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use `JQuery` you can use the JQuery methods `find` and `map`. Then simply use the `Array` method `join`.

```
 var str = $( ".b2" ).find( ".imgbann" );
 str = $.map(str, (e) => $(e).data("id")).join("-") ;
 console.log(str);
```

```js
$('.b2').on('click', function(){
 var str = $( ".b2" ).find( ".imgbann" );
 str = $.map(str, (e) => $(e).data("id")).join("-") ;
 console.log(str);
});
```

```css
.b2{
background:gold;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='b2'>
  <div class='singleb2'>
  <img class='imgbann' src='00.jpg' data-id=53 alt='img'>
</div>

  <div class='singleb2'>
  <img class='imgbann' src='01.jpg' data-id=66 alt='img'>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery's .map() fits this scenario nicely:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

```
$(selector).map(function (index, element) {
  return $(element).data("id");
}).toArray().join("-");
```

In the comments you stated they all had the same class, so can use `.find(".class")`

```js
$('.b2').on('click', function() {
  var str = $(this).find(".imgbann").map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).data("id");
  }).toArray().join("-");
  console.log(str);
});
```

```css
.b2 {
  background: gold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='b2'>
  <div class='singleb2'>
    <img class='imgbann' src='00.jpg' data-id=53 alt='img'>
  </div>

  <div class='singleb2'>
    <img class='imgbann' src='01.jpg' data-id=66 alt='img'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` instead of another nested `.each()` to shorten it a bit.

```
    $('.b2').on('click', function(){
    var str = "";

    $('div', '.b2').each(function(index){
        if(index > 0){
            str += '-';
        }
        str += $(this).find('img').attr('data-id');
    })

    console.log(str); //'53-66'

});
```

Comment: hmm... just without ending `-`

Comment: @puerto surely you can figure that out. the first arg to each is an index

Answer (score 1):

As usual with "get a single value from an array-like structure" questions, the answer is [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It's a good function to learn and understand, as it helps with so many questions.

In this case, I'm getting the elements with the class "imgbann" under the currently clicked `div`, converting the list to an array, then reducing the array to a string.

`reduce` takes a function to which the current value of an "accumulator" variable, the current item in the array. It also takes the index of the current item and the entire array, but for this task we don't need them. The second argument is the initial value of the accumulator if needed.

Then all we need to do is add a hyphen if the accumulator has a value, then the value of the current element's `data-id` attribute.

```js
$('.b2').on('click', function() {
  var str = $(this).find('.imgbann').toArray().reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc.length ? acc + '-' : ''}${cur.getAttribute('data-id')}`, '');
  console.log(str);
});
```

```css
.b2 {
  background: gold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='b2'>
  <div class='singleb2'>
    <img class='imgbann' src='00.jpg' data-id=53 alt='img'>
  </div>

  <div class='singleb2'>
    <img class='imgbann' src='01.jpg' data-id=66 alt='img'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest answer,but it works. Although I have to point out, try adding some padding to your div to space out the elements for the click to work.

```html
<head> 
      <style>
      .b2{
          background-color:red;
          padding: 10px;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="b2">
      <div class="singleb2">
        <img class="imgbann" src="00.jpg" data-id="53" alt="img" />
      </div>

      <div class="singleb2">
        <img class="imgbann" src="01.jpg" data-id="66" alt="img" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      let b2 = document.querySelector(".b2");
    b2.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        let children = Array.from(e.target.children);
        let data = children.map(child=>{
            return child.children[0].dataset.id;
            
        })
        let d = data.join('-');
        console.log(d);
        
        
    

    })
    </script>
```

```js
      let b2 = document.querySelector(".b2");
        b2.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        let children = Array.from(e.target.children);
        let data = children.map(child=>{
            return child.children[0].dataset.id;
            
        })
        let d = data.join('-');
        console.log(d);
        })
```

Comment: Tagged [jquery] and OPs code in jquery.  Why would you provide such an overly verbose vanilla answer?

Comment: I like doing things in plain old vanilla JS.

Comment: Also saw a tag in there for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could push those data-id's to an array and build your string from there. Try this:

```js
$('.b2').on('click', function() {
 var items = $(this).find('img'), 
     hold  = [],
     index = 0;
 
 items.each(function(i, e) {
   hold.push($(items[i]).data('id'));
 });

 $('.str').text('Range is ' + hold[index++] + ' - ' + hold[index++]);
 
});
```

```css
.b2 {
  background: gold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='b2'>
  <div class='singleb2'>
    <img class='imgbann' src='00.jpg' data-id=53 alt='img'>
  </div>

  <div class='singleb2'>
    <img class='imgbann' src='01.jpg' data-id=66 alt='img'>
  </div>
  
  <p class='str'></p>
  
</div>
```